# Outlook Add-in Development : Mail Information Removed While Reply/Reply-All

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, comaddin

I am developing add-in of outlook (Not VSTO).
I want to change content of mail while replying.

Currently i am facing below case :

- I have a mail with body 'abc'
- Now i want to change content from 'abc' to 'abcd' while replying
- I have done that
- But issue is : i am not getting below informations

[image: Reply Mail Format]

I am not getting 'test','from','to','sent','subject',horizontal line.
I am getting only 'ABCD' instead of that.

How to get all of above.

Comment: What code do you use for dealing with items? What events do you handle for the forward actions in Outlook? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev 
I am facing above case in 'Reply' event of 'ItemEvents_10_Event'

Comment: The Reply event gets an instance of the composed item where there properties are not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are dealing with a new item composed, not the original one where all these properties are set (received item).